# How do I make a word bold in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript to populate data in a table which return everything fine.  I would like to make a string bold.  See code below

```
$tr.find('.data').val($('#txtName').val() + '  <strong>Address:<\/strong> ' + $('#txtAddress').val());
```

How do I make only the word "Address" bold?

Comment: What does the HTML look like?  If you're talking about text that is the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>` tag (as your use of ".val()" suggests), you cannot style parts of it. You can apply a style to the value as a whole by styling the `<input>` or `<textarea>`, but all of the value is affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `.data` is a form input element or a `textarea`, you **cannot** make it bold without turning it into a Rich Text area, which requires a lot of additional code files (via a plugin normally) and setup.

If `.data` is just a `td` or `div`, etc, then `.val()` is the wrong way to set the content. If you just use `.html()` the bold will come through, provided it hasn't been overridden in the CSS. Also, you don't need to escape the forward slash:

```
$tr.find('.data').html($('#txtName').val() + '  <strong>Address:</strong> ' + $('#txtAddress').val());
```

Comment: THank you Doug, it was just a td so I made the change and it was what I was looking for.  Thanks!